# How can I copy a socket into an other variable

Tags: perl, sockets

I have a backendserver and different clients who provide different services.

In a thread I wait for incoming TCP connections. Then they should send am message with what type they are, like a robot or a frontend.

On the backend I now wait for the connections and check what type they are, and depending on that I want it to be copied into for example a $frontendSocket:

```
$requestConnectionSocket = new IO::Socket::INET(...);
$frontendSocket;

sub waitForConnection {
    threads->create(sub {
        while(1){
            $newSocket = $requestConnectionSocket->accept();
            $newSocket->recv($message, 1024);
            if ($message eq "Frontend")
                {
                    $frontendSocket = $newSocket;
                    $frontendSocket->send("hello\n");
                }
            if ($message eq "Roboter")
                {$robotSocket = $newSocket;}
            if ($message eq "Sensor")
                {$sensorSocket = $newSocket;}
        }
    });
}
```

When I runt the script, in this thread I can send the message "hello". But when I want to use the socket outside I am not able to use $frontendSocket.

I hope you understand my problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using `IO::Socket` wouldn't you rather use the `accept` method from the package like:

```
my $newSocket = $requestConnectionSocket->accept();
```

This returns an object and I see no issues assigning that object to a differently named scalar reference.

Okay you updated your question with code like the above, now:

> [image: Clippy suggests thread saftey]
>   It looks like you're trying to share state in threads, have you planned your thread safety?

```
# http://perldoc.perl.org/threads/shared.html
use threads;
use threads::shared;
...
my ($requestConnectionSocket, $frontendSocket, $robotSocket, $sensorSocket) :shared;

sub waitForConnection {
    threads->create(sub {
        while(1){
            my $newSocket;
            {
              lock($requestConnectionSocket);
              $newSocket = $requestConnectionSocket->accept();
            }
            $newSocket->recv($message, 1024);
            if ($message eq "Frontend")
                {
                    lock($frontendSocket);
                    $frontendSocket = $newSocket;
                    $frontendSocket->send("hello\n");
                }
            if ($message eq "Roboter")
                {lock($robotSocket); $robotSocket = $newSocket;}
            if ($message eq "Sensor")
                {lock($sensorSocket); $sensorSocket = $newSocket;}
        }
    });
}
... meanwhile, in another context ...
# I have front end work to do now, figure out if I need to lock or wait and on what.
```

Comment: My answer had been to long for a comment so I updated the main question

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but now I got the error message "lock can only be used on shared values" in the line with lock($requestConnectionSocket);

Comment: @KevinRaddatz Right; I'm sure you added `$requestConnectionSocket` to the `my` list that ended in `:shared`. I'll update my answer to show that.

Answer (score 0):

You have multiple threads accessing the same frontendSocket. This is doomed to fail. What is going to happen when one thread receives a new message (and updates the socket with it), but another thread is still working with the previous socket? Can't do this.

Comment: Sounds logical. But is there a workaround? I want a listener socket to handle incoming connections. Then $frontendSocket would be used in a thread where it will receive messages and deliver them to the other clients. Or do I have to let them listen on different ports and assign them directly?

Comment: You'd need a thread with the message queue. Upon getting connection, your listening thread would send a new socket to the queue for later processing.

Comment: I am not exactly sure what you mean with the queue. Can you explain it a bit more detailed?

Comment: You mean I create an additional thread that handles the queue? In the "waitForConnection" thread I wait for the message and pass the message and the socket to the queueThread?

Comment: You do not need another thread. But you need a queue between your main thread and handler thread.